# Get-AdUser Cannot convert to the type system.string

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run the get-aduser query below and I keep getting the error Get-AdUser Cannot convert to the type system.string. Any idea what might be the problem? TIA

```
$Base = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {(Name -like "Department")}).DistinguishedName

Get-ADUser -Filter *  -SearchBase $Base -Properties Name
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that `$base` is an array of OU names, rather than a single OU name.  `-SearchBase` expects a single string and not a collection.  Check the contents of `$base` to be sure.  If it is an array, then you'll need to use some loop structure to deal with them one at a time, or improve your filter to get just the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this, and I can confirm that if your call to `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` returns more than one OU, then the `DistinguishedName` property will be an array rather than a plain string. So you will need to change your call to `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` so that it returns only one.

You can do that by either using the `-ResultSetSize` parameter to only use the first result:

```
$Base = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {(Name -like "Department")} -ResultSetSize 1).DistinguishedName
```

Or change the `Filter` so that it matches only one OU. I assume you're using `-like` because you're using a wildcard in your actual code, so you probably just have to be more specific.

*Update:* If you want users from all the matched OUs, then you can use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6):

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {(Name -like "Department")} |
    ForEach {
        Get-ADUser -Filter *  -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Properties Name
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have about 5 OU's to go through. Will resultsetsize only do 1 OU?

Comment: Yes. Are you trying to get the users from all 5?

Comment: Yes, exactly if possible

Comment: Easy enough. I updated my answer with how to do that.